# How to use service account .json authentication with powershell?

Tags: powershell, google-api, service-accounts

I'm trying to connect to google api using powershell and even thought it's simple using client id and client secret - I use [this tutorial](https://lazyadmin.nl/it/connect-to-google-api-with-powershell/) , I can't find a way to authenticate using service_account token downloaded for my project and pass it to my api call.

Comment: Here is the documentation on [Oauth2 service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).  I have tried a number of times to get it to work with Powershell.   I gave up somewhere around Computing the signature.   I was never able to get the server to accept my code.  I wish you luck and would love to see the code if you get it working.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I managed to achieve this in PowerShell was to use the p12 keyfile which can be downloaded when creating the service account.

To acquire the actual token was also very frustrating. I stripped the code from a module I've downloaded. https://github.com/scrthq/PSGSuite

```
function Get-GoogleToken {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $P12KeyPath,

    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string[]]
    $Scopes,

    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $AppEmail,

    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $AdminEmail
)
function Invoke-URLEncode ($Object) {
    ([String]([System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Object))).TrimEnd('=').Replace('+','-').Replace('/','_')
}
$googleCert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("$P12KeyPath", "notasecret",[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable )
$rsaPrivate = $googleCert.PrivateKey
$rsa = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
$rsa.ImportParameters($rsaPrivate.ExportParameters($true))
$rawheader = [Ordered]@{
    alg = "RS256"
    typ = "JWT"
} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
$header = Invoke-URLEncode ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($rawheader))
[string]$now = Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat "%s"
$createDate = [int]$now.Split(".").Split(",")[0]
$expiryDate = [int]$now.Split(".").Split(",")[0] + 3540
$rawclaims = [Ordered]@{
    iss   = "$AppEmail"
    sub   = "$AdminEmail"
    scope = "$($Scopes -join " ")"
    aud   = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
    exp   = "$expiryDate"
    iat   = "$createDate"
} | ConvertTo-Json
$claims = Invoke-URLEncode ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($rawclaims))
$toSign = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($header + "." + $claims)
$sig = Invoke-URLEncode ($rsa.SignData($toSign,"SHA256"))
$jwt = $header + "." + $claims + "." + $sig
$fields = [Ordered]@{
    grant_type = 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer'
    assertion  = $jwt
}
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token" -Method Post -Body $fields -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
$messageResponse = $messageResponse | ConvertFrom-Json
return $messageResponse.access_token
}
```

Simply call the function with the correct params and it should work!

```
Get-GoogleToken -P12KeyPath "C:\Users\blabla.p12" -Scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user" -AppEmail "youreAppEmail@yourapp.com" -AdminEmail "admin@yourapp.com"
```

Hope this helps you,
Cheers